# Select distinct data on query

Tags: linq, lambda

I've been stuck on my query on select a distinct data..

**Assume Datas**

- Peter
- Jose
- Joseph
- Peter
- Juan
- Michael
- Peter

But they have different ID's `(Primary key ID on SQL Table)`

Here is what I tried so far

```
var query = (from a in db.Employees
             join b in db.People on a.PersonId equals b.PersonId
             where a.IsSeparated != true
             select b).Distinct();
```

and

```
  var query = db.Employees.Join(db.People, x => x.PersonId, y => y.PersonId, (x, y) => new { x, y })
                .Where(z => z.x.IsSeparated != true).GroupBy(t => t.y.CompleteName).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault());
```

but both query still displaying all data. What I want on my query is if there is a duplicate data make it distinct.

If you guys comment on lambda please explain i'm still learning on how to use it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ join with distinct resultset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373087/linq-join-with-distinct-resultset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with following LINQ :

```
var query = (from a in db.Employees
             join b in db.People on a.PersonId equals b.PersonId
             where a.IsSeparated != true
             select b).GroupBy(x=> new { x.PersonId}).Select(x=>x.First());
```

Comment: yeah, it would group by PersonId.

Comment: the duplicate names has different id's.

Comment: then  you can group by CompleteName

Comment: Sorry for the late I tested it and also i try `.Select(x=>x);` still the same problem :'(

Comment: If you have two different completename and you want to group by completename, it will give two result which is distinct to each other. You need to make sure, on what basis, you want to make your resultset distinct. So, based on those criteria, you can groupby

Comment: Not yet but i'm still trying different codes.. I'm on Trial and Error now.

Comment: If i use a linqpad I solve it.. maybe i have a problem in passing it in the viewbag selectlist (dropdown on html).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157038/discussion-between-akash-kc-and-kira).

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = (from a in db.Employees
             join b in db.People on a.PersonId equals b.PersonId
             where a.IsSeparated != true
             select b)
             .GroupBy(x=> x.CompleteName)
             .Select(grp => grp.Value.First());
```

Comment: Sorry got an error `cannot convert lambda expression to type string because its not a delegate type` on `.Select` part